# Backslashing apostrophes as they enter the database

Tags: php, mysql

Solved previous part of problem, still need to understand why this isn't working though :)

Reverting back to escaping the strings separately, I have this.

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (firstname,surname,email,password,birthday,birthmonth,birthyear,houseno,streetname,town,country,postcode,phonenumber,singer,songwriter,producer,composer,band,instrument,instrument2,extra,confirmcode) VALUES ('".$firstname."','".$surname."','".$email."','".$password."',".$birthday.",".$birthmonth.",".$birthyear.",'".$houseno."','".$streetname."','".$town."','".$country."','".$postcode."',".$phonenumber.",".$singer.",".$songwriter.",".$producer.",".$composer.", ".$band.",'".$instrument."','".$instrument2."','".$extra."','".$rand."')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($surname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($stown),
    mysql_real_escape_string($houseno),
    mysql_real_escape_string($streetname),
    mysql_real_escape_string($extra),
    mysql_real_escape_string($email)) or die ('pood'); 
    echo $streetname;
```

I'm getting the die error - so it doesn't echo $streetname; (which should be 'Clark\'s Way'), and doesn't seem to backslash apostrophe as it's not being entered into the database.

Apologies if I haven't done my research to your standards, but I've been trying to understand why this isn't working for hours.

Thanks :)

Comment: Escape each input value, not the entire query. Better yet, use parameterized queries with [MySQLi or PDO](http://us3.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and don't bother with escaping.

Comment: Verify if all int fields aren't surrounded by '' and that other fields do

Comment: :D
I'll have a look at parameterized queries. Thanks. My friend (who's waaay better with this stuff than me) changed the seperate escape_strings to this big one as they weren't working properly. I know what's causing it now though so I can try and figure out how to fix it

Comment: The #1 reason to use parametrized queries is to avoid SQL injection.  The #2 reason is to avoid the pain you're going through now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query()` doesn't take multiple arguments like that. You need to escape each variable *within* the string of the query. Like this:

```
... VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."','".mysql_r...
```

So, you'd end up with something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,surname,email,password,birthday,
birthmonth,birthyear,houseno,streetname,town,country,postcode,
phonenumber,singer,songwriter,producer,composer,band,instrument,
instrument2,extra,confirmcode) VALUES (
'". mysql_real_escape_string($firstname) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($surname) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($email) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($password) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($birthday) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($birthmonth) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($birthyear) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($houseno) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($streetname) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($town) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($country) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($postcode) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($phonenumber) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($singer) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($songwriter) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($producer) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($composer) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($band) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($instrument) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($instrument2) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($extra) ."',
'". mysql_real_escape_string($rand) ."')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Sorry if there's a typo in there. But I think you get the idea.

---

Here's an (untested) example of how a parameterized query might work, adapted from the examples [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,surname,email,password,birthday,
birthmonth,birthyear,houseno,streetname,town,country,postcode,
phonenumber,singer,songwriter,producer,composer,band,instrument,
instrument2,extra,confirmcode) VALUES (
:firstname, :surname, :email, :password, :birthday, :birthmonth,
:birthyear, :houseno, :streetname, :town, :country, :postcode, :phonenumber,
:singer, :songwriter, :producer, :composer, :band, :instrument, :instrument2,
:extra, :rand)";

// assume $dbh is your PDO database connection
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$sth->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
$sth->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sth->bindParam(':password', $password);
$sth->bindParam(':birthday', $birthday);
// and so on...

$sth->execute();
```

Comment: @Joshua'J-Dawg'Oakley I'll see if I can also cook up an example with a parameterized query (prepared statement) to show you what that would look like. Keep in mind this is all untested, but it should give you the general idea. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to do that, I tried typing it out myself and only escaping the relevant ones (not integers), but I'm getting some kind of syntax error (which aren't turned on on my server for some reason), then I tried copying what you wrote and I get the same problem. I'll try undoing it all and adding 1 escape string at a time

Comment: @Joshua'J-Dawg'Oakley I should be around for a little while yet, so if you want to continue discussing this, how 'bout you [join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20783/) so we don't clutter up the comments on this page.

Comment: Thankyou, you beautiful man! It works, well when I only used mysql_real_escape_string on $streetname, I'll try and add further variables one by one to see if they work.

Edit: Sorry, didn't see your comment but good point ^^

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the backslash-quotes.  Remove the backslashes and it looks like it should work.

Before:   `VALUES (\'Joshua\',\'Oakley\',`
After:   `VALUES ('Joshua','Oakley',`

Comment: Yeah I figured this, is there a way to change the $query to stop putting backslashes on the opening and closing apostrophe? :)